# Facebook "view on ..." text on custom story is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I'm implementing deep linking in an app.
Followed every tutorial I found.
Tested every possible setting.

And the result is: If I post a story with "user_generated": "true", Facebook posts the big photo as it should, but there is no link like "view on Instagram", "view on Foursqare" and so on. So people can't reach the actual object.

Facebook settings:
Display Name, Namespace, App Domains, Site URL, Bundle ID, iPhone Store ID, Deep Linking (ON), Native or desktop app?(ON), Is your App Secret embedded?(OFF)

App Restrictions - No restrictions

I'v set up the open graph action and object and they are working without "user_generated": "true".

I'm sending my code (projectnamespace is replaced for this example):

```
-(void) shareOnFacebook: (NSString *) image {

NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];

object.provisionedForPost = YES;
object[@"type"] = @"projectnamespace:photo";
object[@"title"] = _postText.text;
object[@"url"] = responseJson[@"share"];
object[@"og:url"] = responseJson[@"share"];
object[@"al:web"] = responseJson[@"share"];
object[@"web"] = responseJson[@"share"];

if (image) {
    NSLog(@"Photo Link: %@", image);
    object[@"image"] = @[@{@"url": image, @"user_generated" : @"true" }];
}

// Post custom object
[FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        NSString *objectId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
        id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];

        [action setObject:objectId forKey:@"photo"];
        [action setObject: @"true" forKey: @"fb:explicitly_shared"];

        if (image)
            [action setImage:@[@{@"url": image, @"user_generated" : @"true" }]];

        // create action referencing user owned object
        [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/projectnamespace:add" graphObject:action completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if(!error) {
                NSString *actionId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSLog(@"Posted story to facebook: %@", actionId);
                [self shareAndDismiss: nil];
            } else {
                // An error occurred
                NSLog(@"Encountered an error posting action to Open Graph: %@", error);
                [self shareAndDismiss: nil];
            }
        }];

    } else {
        // An error occurred
        NSLog(@"Error posting the Open Graph object to the Object API: %@", error);
        [self shareAndDismiss: nil];
    }
}];
}
```

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I have seen, there is no such "View on Foursquare" link on Foursquare posts being shared on Facebook.

The only "View on..." links that I am aware of are for Instagram. However Instagram is a Facebook company. The Facebook and Instagram teams work together for their own photo-sharing experience, which means they are not limited by the API as we are.

I'm afraid that "View on Instagram" is a special feature given to the Instagram app only and that the Facebook API doesn't give that ability to others apps.